# How to pretty print JSON with brackets?

Tags: json, go

I am able to nicely indent my JSON with the below code, it prints something like first output. But I would like the output to be enclosed with an array and to be properly indented, like in the second output.

```
j, err := json.MarshalIndent(x, "", "  ")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println(string(j))
}

{
    "A" : "x",
    "B" : "y",
    "C" : [
        { 
            "A" ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Like so.

```
[
    {
        "A" : "x",
        "B" : "y",
        "C" : [
           { 
              "A" ...
           }

        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your variable `x` in a single element slice. The slice gets encoded to a JSON array (which use the square brackets):

```
j, err := json.MarshalIndent([]interface{}{x}, "", "  ")
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Q9kqTdwoO6

Comment: thanks, this worked perfectly. Well we're at it, my struct has a slice in it which may be nil, any suggestions on how to print the nil as '[]' when marshaled to json?